# Sveltekit, Depencencies working in dev but not loading directly in the routed page after build

Tags: chart.js, vite, sveltekit

In a sveltekit project where **everything works in dev**,  some dependencies seems not to be working when build at routed pages.

In specific `charts.js` is working in dev well, but is not working in a routed page `/page` when the it is build for production.

It is hard to debug as there is no error messages, but there are significantly less GET request when going to `/page` and if I go to the main page and then use a `<a/>` link to the route, everything works fine.

What could be the reason behind this? Am I missing some configuration? Probably the route is not expected to be fetched directly?

pd: I'm using svelte-chartjs library.

the component looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Doughnut } from 'svelte-chartjs';
  export datax = 10
  export datay = 20

  import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
    CategoryScale,
  } from 'chart.js'


  let chart: Doughnut;
  let data = {
      labels: ['Pension', 'Monthly paid out salary', 'Tax Under', 'Tax Over'],
    datasets: [
      {
      label: 'Danish Kronws',
      data: [datax , datay],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 134,159,0.4)',
        'rgba(98,  182, 239,0.4)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 134, 159, 1)',
        'rgba(98,  182, 239, 1)',
      ],
      },
    ],
  };

  ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale);

  $: {if (chart) {
      chart.data.datasets[0].data = [datax ,datay]
    }
  }

</script>

<div class="chart">
  <Doughnut bind:chart data={data} options={options} />

</div>

<style>
  .chart{
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `ChartJS.register` should be in `onMount` as mentioned. Maybe the entire `Doughnut` component should be guarded via an `{#if}`.

Comment: Also, what adapter are you building with?

Comment: i will try your suggestion, thanks, I'm using node, but tried others with no luck

Comment: @H.B.  many thanks again/', but still no luck, even using onMount and putting the if, everything goes ok in dev, but as soon as I build, still not working. In any case in the docs of the library there is no reference to onMount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When navigation to the page works but direct access does not, that is a sign that there are issues with server-side rendering. The first access to a page is rendered on the server by default which can cause issues.

E.g. your page code has to avoid accessing any browser APIs outside of [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount) as those will not be available on the server. Check the console of the server process and the console in the browser for errors.

You can also [turn off SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) by adding an export to `+page.js`/`ts`.

```js
export const ssr = false;
```

I would only recommend this for finding out whether SSR is the problem. Turning it off permanently should only be done in rare occasions when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Interesting, but this solutions seems not to be working in this case, thanks anyway! there is also no logs in the browser or terminal to debug, I'll check if it is a issue related to svelte-chartsjs.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem, people might be able to help.

Comment: not sure what is the best way to provide a minimal example of something like that as there is lots of things involved, but the issue can be observed here: http://74.208.40.117:5173 (click in log in, then works) vs going  http://74.208.40.117:5173/dashboard  then doesn't work.